# How to reinitialize ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, swiper.js

I have an angular app using [iDangerous Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/) with the following html:

```
<div ng-repeat="slide in slides">
  <img src="{{slide.url}}" />
</div>
```

and the JS

```
$scope.slides = [{url: 'myimage1.jpg'},{url: 'myimage2.jpg'}];
```

The Swiper library takes control of the DOM. When swiper parameters are changed, the swiper instance must be destroyed and recreated. But when the wiper instance is destroyed, the `<img>` elements that were originally created by angular (i.e. repeated) are destroyed also.

How do I force angular to re-initialize the ng-repeat (i.e. load the `<img>` elements again)?

Comment: are there any events that the swiper API provides when it gets destroyed?  If so, you should be able to leverage that to instigate a change in your controller to *reset* the slides.

Comment: @jusopi Yes there is an onDestroy() method. What's the angular method to do the reset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*preface - I'm not familiar with Swiper or iDangerous so I'm not entirely sure how you call this*

I found the `onDestroy` callback via the swiper docs here - http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/#.VpVBo5MrJE4

You should be able to do something like this:

```
var swiper = new Swiper( ... )
swiper.onDestroy( function....

//or

swiper.on( 'destroy', function(){ 
    $scope.$apply( function() {
        $scope.slides = []; //or whatever you want to do here
    }
});
```

The reason I am suggesting the `$scope.$apply` is because the swiper *destroy* event happens outside of the concern of angular and therefore may occur within/outside of the $digest cycle.  This may or may not be necessary.

#### edit (addt. findings)

So one thing I found while tooling around with this was that when you use the `$scope.params` to initialize your `mySwiper` instance, it actually adds additional values to that object.  When you go to reuse it, it's in a state that Swiper is unhappy with and will throw an error.  So the easy fix is to copy your `$scope.params` object and pass that to a `getSwiper` method.

```
function getSwiper(){
    var p = angular.copy($scope.params)
    var s = new Swiper('.swiper-container', p)

    return s;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/VezwVP/?editors=001

#### so to answer your question

> How do I force angular to re-initialize the ng-repeat (i.e. load the elements again) ?

Usually it's enough to just set the `ng-repeat`'s *collection* value on the scope to trigger the change.  In some cases you need to force this, then you can hack it (though I don't recommend it always):

```
var orig = $scope.slides;
$scope.slides = []; //triggers a $digest
$scope.slides = orig;
```

Comment: then you can remove the $apply call

Comment: also, do you need to re-assign the values of `slides` back to their original value?  If so, let me know and I will amend the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Big problem: Swiper is actually removes the <div>.

Comment: oh... yeah that kinda changes things.  Is there a way you can set up an example in jsbin or plunkr?  You're probably going to need to write a directive to handle this

Comment: Here's a simple pen. The images are not removed by swiper...but I still don't  get get the swiper recreated properly. I believe a directive to destroy/replace the <div ng-repeat> could work.

Comment: Did you forget the link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100512/discussion-between-jusopi-and-lilbiscuit).